# an issue with slf4j in a Java application

Tags: java, slf4j

I am trying to config slf4j on Netbeans using Java application(not web).
I added libraries :

- slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar
- slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar

My code likes this:

```
public class TestLogger {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestLogger.class);
    logger.info("Hello worlds");
}
}
```

and I don't have any pom.xml which is mentioned a lot in some guides I read.
what is it?

My output:

```
run:
Failed to instantiate SLF4J LoggerFactory
Reported exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Level
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:128)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:108)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:279)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:252)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:265)
at testlogger.TestLogger.main(TestLogger.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Level
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 6 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:       org/apache/log4j/Level
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:128)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:108)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:279)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:252)
at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:265)
at testlogger.TestLogger.main(TestLogger.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Level
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 6 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I know I must config  a .xml file so that slf4j could run smoothly.
but I don't know how and where.

P/s: what is pom.xml? I saw it a lot in some tutorials.

Comment: `pom.xml` is only needed if you use Maven.

Answer (score 0):

If you only included those two libraries, you are missing the core log4j12 library, which is the actual logger implementation.

However, log4j12 is obsolete and no longer supported, so you should be using log4j2, in which case there are two libraries, the api and "core" that you will need to download.

Comment: i added log4j-1.2.16.jar into libraries and debug theng i got output like this:`log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (testlogger.TestLogger).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
`